# OAuth Token works for userInfo but not to Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, oauth-2.0

Can someone tell me why I can't use the same token to retrieve userInfo and calendars list from Google?

I have set the correct scopes (I think):

```
  private static final String PLUS_ME_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
  private static final String USER_INFO_PROFILE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
  private static final String USER_INFO_EMAIL_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";
  private static final String GOOGLE_CALENDAR_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
```

To get the user info I use this url: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token= and for calendars I use: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?minAccessRole=writer&key= .

In user Info I get all the correct info but for the calendar I get Error 401 : Login Required.

What's wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

> https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?minAccessRole=writer&key=

to

> https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?minAccessRole=writer&access_token=

Just that simple ;)

**UPDATE:**

Also note, that it is **not recommended** to specify the [access token as a query parameter](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-22#page-7):

> Because of the security weaknesses associated with the URI method (see Section 5), including the high likelihood that the URL containing the access token will be logged, it SHOULD NOT be used unless it is impossible to transport the access token in the "Authorization" request header field or the HTTP request entity-body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan and for de advice.

Comment: so can I make the same call, and pass the token in the header (instead of the query-param)? something like this https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?minAccessRole=writer (and the token in the header)? thanks

Comment: @Jan, can you please have a look here? I've got a problem using Google APIs... maybe you can help :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316783/using-google-api-with-spring-security-oauth2-0