# Using Google API with spring-security-oauth2.0

Tags: spring-security, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I've searched here a bit but could not find an answer to my issue.

I implement oAuth client with **spring-sec-oAuth 2.0** (1.0.0.RC2a). After properly setting the beans.xml, I happily get a valid token and all looks good. Then, I want to use Calendar APIs - I'm not sure how do I make the call to get the Calendar object.

My (relevant) settings: (spring-servlet.xml)

```
<!--apply the oauth client context-->
<oauth:client   id="oauth2ClientFilter" />

<oauth:resource id="google" 
    type="authorization_code" 
    client-id="<my client id>" 
    client-secret="<my client secret>"
    access-token-uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" 
    user-authorization-uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
    scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
    client-authentication-scheme="form"
    pre-established-redirect-uri="https://ohad.sealdoc.com/oauth2-client/hello" />

<bean id="googleClientService" class="com...GoogleClientServiceImpl">
    <property name="butkeDemoRestTemplate">
        <oauth:rest-template resource="google" />
    </property>
```

and the implementation class:

```
public class GoogleClientServiceImpl implements DemoService 
{
    private RestOperations butkeDemoRestTemplate;

    @Override
    public String getTrustedMessage() 
    {
        String dataUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?minAccessRole=writer";

        Calendar service = butkeDemoRestTemplate.getForObject(dataUri, Calendar.class);
        return "demo";
    }

}
```

Doing so ends up with:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   error="invalid_request",
>   error_description="{errors=[{domain=usageLimits,
>   reason=accessNotConfigured, message=Access Not Configured}], code=403,
>   message=Access Not Configured}"

Definitely, I'm doing something wrong in my "getTrustedMessage()", so I'm hear to consult the experts... I DO want to use OAuth2RestTemplate, but how do I know the URI I should use? After searching (Google), I found only examples of Google code, and they use Google oAuth (which I do not want to use - I'd rather use Spring implementation for my client)

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please point me to a nice article where I can implement my own OAuth Application based on Spring Security and Use Google as the provider. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Anand I think the best article is Spring-Security-oAuth wiki page. you have there all details of writing your client and protected-resource, and the identity-provider will be google, so you have to configure the XML of the protected-resource. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2

Comment: How and when user is redirected to the consent page? I am trying to implement user registration using Oauth2 & Google as provider.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664846/user-registration-login-using-spring-security-oauth-2-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GOT IT!**

I've resolved this problem (getting the "403, message=Access Not Configured" thing) by simply enabling the specific service in [Google APIs Console, under "Services"](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:996986975307%3aservices)...