# Spring security with Google+

Tags: spring-security, google-plus

What is the correct way of integrating Google+ login with Spring Security?

I saw that there is http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/, but not sure how (and if it's possible) to integrate with Google+.

Comment: I think Spring Social already has the necessary classes to work with G+. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316783/using-google-api-with-spring-security-oauth2-0 and this post: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/725727-google-automatic-signin-using-google-token-received-from-android-application]. Also, pac4j (https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j) is attempting to provide a similar set of features.

Comment: I know about pac4j, but it seems like a whole new project that offers just a Spring security interface. The module that I was referring in my question seems a good start, but I couldn't find good documentation on it.